# Django Python Social Auth only allow certain users to sign in

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I want only users from a @companyname.net email *or* from a list of email addresses to be able to sign in with Python Social Auth through google+. How would I accomplish this?

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['companyname.net']
```

is what I currently have in settings.py, but that only allows @companyname.net-ers to sign in.

Comment: This list you have is domain-dependent? I mean, you will allow all emails from specific domains or just specific email addresses?

Comment: I want to allow **everyone** for @companyname.net and only some specific others from other domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting the registration to some emails OR domains is called [whitelisting](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#whitelists).

As the documentation explains, you have two possible ways of whitelisting, namely by supplying a

- list of domains to be whitelisted, `SOCIAL_AUTH_<BACKEND_NAME>_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['foo.com', 'bar.com']`
- list of email addresses to be whitelisted, `SOCIAL_AUTH_<BACKEND_NAME>_WHITELISTED_EMAILS = ['me@foo.com', 'you@bar.com']`

Since OP wants

> to allow everyone for @companyname.net and only some specific others from other domains.

then OP can keep using `SOCIAL_AUTH_<BACKEND_NAME>_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS` as OP is already doing and also introduce `SOCIAL_AUTH_<BACKEND_NAME>_WHITELISTED_EMAILS` to add the specific emails OP wants also to login.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is overriding python-social-auth pipeline.

You can override create_user with something like:

```
def create_user(strategy, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if user:
        return {'is_new': False}

    allowed_emails = get_list_of_emails()

    fields = dict((name, kwargs.get(name, details.get(name)))
                  for name in strategy.setting('USER_FIELDS', USER_FIELDS))
    if not fields:
        return

    if fields[email] in allowed_emails:        
        return {
            'is_new': True,
            'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
        }

    return
```

This method `get_list_of_emails()` is to be used as a way to load the emails from file ou from database. It needs to return a list of emails.

Then, in the SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE in your settings you replace the create_user to your custom method:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'path.to.my.method.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

This way you can keep the domais whitelist, and then store the emails you want somewhere where you can load them with the method `get_list_of_emails()`

more on the [docs](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline)

Comment: I didn't tested it, but it should work. Debug to see if the email is really a key of fields

Comment: How would I return the user to a specific page if the user's email is not in allowed_emails?

Comment: Just set SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL, in settings.py,  to the url you want the user to be redirected

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tested implementation:

```
import os
import psycopg2
from Utils.common import setup_logging

LOG = setup_logging(__name__)
USER_FIELDS = ['username', 'email']


def get_whitelisted_emails():
    whitelisted_domains_emails = []
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user=os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
                                      password=os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
                                      host='localhost',
                                      port=os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
                                      database=os.environ.get('DB_NAME'))
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        get_whitelisted_domains_emails = "SELECT domain, email FROM cortex_emails WHERE is_active=True;"
        cursor.execute(get_whitelisted_domains_emails)
        whitelisted_domains_emails = cursor.fetchall()
        connection.close()
    except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        LOG.info('Failed to connect to database...')

    return [email for _, email in whitelisted_domains_emails]


def create_user(strategy, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if user:
        return {'is_new': False}

    allowed_emails = get_whitelisted_emails()

    fields = dict((name, kwargs.get(name, details.get(name)))
                  for name in strategy.setting('USER_FIELDS', USER_FIELDS))
    if not fields:
        return

    if fields['email'] in allowed_emails:
        return {
            'is_new': True,
            'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
        }

    return
```